# Operand is incorrect type

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this [MIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set) assembly code:

```
...
bgez $a0, kosul_3
li   $v0, $zero
j    dongu

kosul_3:
...
```

The error is:

> $zero operand is incorrect type

How can I solve it?

Comment: Where is that error happening? There are no problems with the code posted. Also, this isn't a problem with recursive code, per se, so you might want to change the title.

Comment: `li` is load integer and you tried to use a register. You want `li $v0, 0`. Next time please copy the code as text and not as a picture.